# Transpose and create new record in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge data sheet with thousands of contacts with multiple email addresses. I'm trying to copy each unique email address and create a new record with the same contact name but each with a unique email to it resulting in 3 columns: First Name | Last Name | Email instead of first name | last name | email 1 | email 2 | email 3| etc

an example of what I'm trying to accomplish in this photo:

sample of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: sample of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Google Sheets is off-topic here, on-topic on our sister site,  [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).  Solutions aren't always 100% transferable between the two.  If you are using Sheets, you might want to have this migrated (and retagged for Google Sheets), to ensure you get a working solution.

Comment: Use Power Query.  Select the first two columns.  Then UNPIVOT Other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround for this...

I cut the columns D, E over to the right two columns each and then filled int he blanks with the first and last name so I ended up with 9 columns

first name|lastname|email1|first name|Last Name| email2| First name| Last Name | Email 3

Then I cut and pasted them under each other, used a filter to sort and deleted the rows with blanks and ended up with

first name|last name|email

and ended up with separate records, of multiple instances of the same name but with a unique email address for uploading into my ESP.

it works! problem solved!

Comment: Kudos for solving this.  You can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark.  That will indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Convert or transpose excel report (horizontal) to tabular (vertical) format for importing](https://superuser.com/questions/1652796/convert-or-transpose-excel-report-horizontal-to-tabular-vertical-format-for)

per Ron Rosenfeld and Emily
The steps are shown below and super easy. Just replace

(Style with First)
(Color with Last)
(SO - Email1)
(S2 - Email2)
(S4 - Email3)